# Telegram bot message format

Tags: bots, photo, telegram

There is an image in the telegram docs showing a
Formatted message with an image and text under,
It's from TechCrunch.
I have tried to replicate this  and failed.
How can one replicate this format.
I am using  Python

```
    def reply(msg=None, img=None):
        if msg:
            resp = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL + 'sendPhoto', urllib.urlencode({
                'chat_id': str(chat_id),
                'caption': msg,
            })).read()
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are talking about [this image](https://core.telegram.org/file/811140081/1/VldnlW70g2I/a140b0216e7d156ebc) here i'm pretty sure it was done with `sendPhoto()` method. Text can be placed under the image by using the optional `caption` parameter.

[Telegram Bot API sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)

Comment: I was asking about formatting of messages I know about sendPhoto method of api, I should have used in in my question.

Comment: I am wondering is there hacks or markup injections that developers are using to achieve better formatting for branding etc?

Comment: After tinkering it seems like one just has to get the image size that suits best. Maybe more options in future api, but I like telegram !